# Executor Map doesn't run a function

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to reproduce a race condition. The code below works fine with submit used instead of map but I want to understand why map doesn't run the update method.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time


class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 100  # shared data

    def update(self, transaction, amount):
        print(f'{transaction} started')
        tmp_amount = self.balance  # reading from db
        tmp_amount += amount
        time.sleep(1)
        self.balance = tmp_amount
        print(f'{transaction} ended')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    acc = BankAccount()
    print(f'Main started. acc.Balance={acc.balance}')

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as ex:
        ex.map(acc.update, [dict(transaction='refill', amount=100),
                            dict(transaction='withdraw', amount=-200)])

    print(f'End of Main. Balance={acc.balance}')
```

Comment: From the docs of ``Executor.map``: "If a func call raises an exception, then that exception will be raised when its value is retrieved from the iterator." You don't retrieve the value, thus hiding the error: ``update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'``. Note that ``map`` does not unpack your ``dict``, it just assigns it to the first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass each kind of argument in a separate iterable.

```
ex.map(acc.update, ['refill', 'withdraw'], [100, -200])
```

---

Like `map`, [`Executor.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) takes one iterable per argument, and assigns *from each* iterable to *one* argument. In addition, errors are not propagated until the result is actually accessed.

> [Executor.map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map)
>
> Similar to `map(func, *iterables)` ...
>
> If a *func* call raises an exception, then that exception will be raised when its value is retrieved from the iterator.

Thus, the code incorrectly passes the arguments, but suppresses the error. Fetching the values, e.g. via `list(ex.map(...))` reveals the error:

```
TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'
```

Creating a separate iterable for each kind of argument prevents this.

```
#                  V transaction
ex.map(acc.update, ['refill', 'withdraw'], [100, -200])
#                                          ^ amount
```

It may be desirable to order arguments by call, not by kind. Use `zip` and `*` unpacking to convert the input as required by `map`.

```
ex.map(acc.update, *zip(('refill', 100), ('withdraw', 200)))
```

---

If keyword arguments are desired, a helper is required to unpack the arguments.

```
def kwargify(func):
    """Wrap ``func`` to accept a dictionary of keyword arguments"""
    return lambda kwargs: func(**kwargs)
```

Simply wrap the desired function with this helper when passing it to `ex.map`:

```
    ex.map(
        kwargify(acc.update),
        [
            dict(transaction='refill', amount=100),
            dict(transaction='withdraw', amount=-200)
        ]
    )
```

Comment: I got it. But is there any way to pass arguments by keywords (without accepting **kwargs on the function's side)?

Comment: @EngineerSpock I've added some examples how ``map`` can be used more naturally, including with keywords.